# Destroy consume memory

Tags: android

**hello friends**

i have develop one application in which i have lots of **images and sound**,

i can release sound easily by `release()` method but i can't able to release image.
can you tell me how can i release image ?
earlier i have use `system.gc()` function but it is not working for image i thing it is garbage collector.
second thing is that can you give me precaution step against `memory management` (***regarding of image,sound & codeing part also***)

**Thanks

nik**

Comment: http://mobworld.wordpress.com/2010/07/05/memory-management-in-android/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invocations of `System.gc()` are only suggestions to run the garbage collector. The GC need not run immediately.

I believe such complex applications would benefit from using an MVC model. The Model (or logic) class can save the required images and sounds to a cache folder, and just pass the list of file paths to the view (Activity) which can read and display on-demand, de-referencing any assets that are no longer required.

Also, it would help to reduce the asset sizes (images and sounds) by lowering  resolutions (image) or downsampling (audio), wherever possible.

Update:
- For downsampling images, check this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize

MVC is slightly tougher to implement in Android due to the fact that Activities are the entry points. So, what can be done is that a singleton "Model" object can be created, which can be accessed from anywhere. Similarly, a singleton "Controller" object can also be created. The activity can notify the controller when it requires an asset, and the controller will forward the request to the model.

Comment: example for MVC? or reducing asset sizes?

Comment: both of MVC and reducing asset sizes

Comment: MVC is a much tougher topic. Let's move this discussion to chat. Do you know how to move to chat?

Comment: ya i know that but currently i am not, chat not allow you understand

Comment: send me any link so i can see it

Comment: I mean, chat on stackoverflow.com. Look at the top. There is a chat option. Is that too not allowed?

Comment: @nik let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2251/discussion-between-sparkymat-and-nik)

Comment: click on the link in my previous msg